# List all the years between dates

Tags: php

I am looking to list every year between dates using PHP and Mysql data base, the code is this:

```
<?php

$start    = new DateTime('2010-12-02');
$start->modify('first day of this month');
$end      = new DateTime('2016-05-06');
$end->modify('first day of next month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 year');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("Y") . "<br>\n";
}

?>
```

Output

```
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
```

**Missing the year 2016.**

How I can do to make 2016 also returns? It should return as it does to 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$start    = '2010-12-02';
$end      = '2016-05-06';
$getRangeYear   = range(gmdate('Y', strtotime($start)), gmdate('Y', strtotime($end)));
print_r($getRangeYear);
```

use the range function to get list of ranging numbers, first parameter start range, and second ending range..
http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Answer (score 0):

It is simple: you are iterating between `2010-12-02` and `2016-05-06`. The generated dates are:

- `2010-12-02` -> ok
- `2011-12-02` -> ok
- `2012-12-02` -> ok
- `2013-12-02` -> ok
- `2014-12-02` -> ok
- `2015-12-02` -> ok
- `2016-12-02` -> over `2016-05-06` - stop algorithm.

I do not know exactly what do you want to do, but it seem that you should change end date.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $start    = new DateTime('2010-12-02')->modify('+1 year');
    $start->modify('first day of this month');
    $end      = new DateTime('2016-05-06');
    $end->modify('first day of next month');
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 year');
    $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    foreach ($period as $dt) {
        echo $dt->format("Y") . "<br>\n";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Just edit the first line of the code.After a year I hope it still helps some other people.